# Why to use jpadialect in JpaTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jta

I am learning spring 3.0 from Spring in Action.

There it talks about importance of having jpadialect in JpaTranactionManager

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
              class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
          <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
          <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
        </bean>
<bean id="jpaDialect"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
```

However the dialect is already present in declaration of entityManagerFactory via jpaVendorAdaptor.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class= "org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
</bean>
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
  <property name="database" value="HSQL" />
  <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
  <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
  <property name="databasePlatform"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
</bean>  
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource. DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
   <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/spitter/spitter" />
   <property name="username" value="sa" />
   <property name="password" value="" />
 </bean>
```

Is the use of dialect in JpaTranactionManager redundant?

Comment: No redundant!! This link will help you a lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649583/jpa-provider-vs-dialect-vs-vendor-in-the-spring-contaniner-configuration !!

Comment: Thanks, could you post it as ans. I will accept it

Comment: @S Kr I post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `jpaDialect` in `JpaTransactionManager` is no redundant to `jpaVendorAdapter` config. Their config have different purpose.

You can refer [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18649583/jpa-provider-vs-dialect-vs-vendor-in-the-spring-contaniner-configuration) with good explanation.